# what is the check_transformer_data_not_an_array test from sklearn's check_estimator intended to?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, package

I am trying to get in house made transformers pass the **check_estimator** tests and there is one test, that I am not too sure what it is intended for.

The transformers fail the **check_transformer_data_not_an_array** because the input is a **_NotAnArray** class, and my package transformers don't like that. The transformers are intended to work only with dataframes, and I added a workaround to transform numpy arrays into df to pass most of the check_estimators tests.

**_NotAnArray** is a class developed in the Scikit-learn library, which purpose I do not know. And I guess the test **check_transformer_data_not_an_array** also has a purpose, unbeknownst to me.

My question is:

What is **check_transformer_data_not_an_array** intended for? Or in other words, why is it important?

And if anybody knows as well, why the class **_NotAnArray** was created / needed, that would also help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scikit-learn estimators should validate X and y. This validation will convert the input X and y into a NumPy array to do the numerical operation of the estimator.

**check_transformer_data_not_an_array** makes sure that passing an array-like (but
not a NumPy array) is still working as if passing an array.

It basically ensures that the validation under the hood happen. The validation is done by the check_X_y class

This was actually an answer I got from one of Scikit-learn developers through the mailing list :)

Comment: So does that mean making a custom sklearn-estimator with non-numpy-array input is okay? You just need to make sure passing in array input / "your custom input" works the same way underneath the hood?

Comment: Yes, it is allowed and if you want to make the transformer fully compatible with sklearn, this should be implemented. However, depending on what you are trying to develop, you might not need to add this additional functionality. For example, in Feature-engine, we  support only numpy arrays and pandas dataframes.